# Populating an HTML Table from SQL DB with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm attempting to populate a table in HTML with data from a DB. It's not working properly (a blank white page is displayed), but I can't find the source of the error.

```
<?php    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders";
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $order_id = $row['orderID'];
  $order_due = $row['order_due'];
  $order_subject = $row['order_subject'];
  $order_level = $row['order_level'];
  $order_pages = $row['order_pages'];
  $order_cost = $row['order_cost']); 
  echo "<tr><td>".$order_id."</td><td>".$order_due."</td><td>".$order_subject."</td><td>".$order_level."</td><td>".$order_pages."</td><td>".$order_cost."</td></tr>";   
}
 echo "</table>";
 ?>
```

Comment: try at the top of the script `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - see what will be reported

Comment: Placed this in the PHP tag right at the top of the page, still just a blank white page after refreshing (In Firefox), tried it in IE and got a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Use: ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1); That should hopefully give you an error message.

Comment: Nope... same blank page :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$order_cost = $row['order_cost']);
```

you have an extra paranthesis

Also change this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

to

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Comment: Though when I add rows to the DB only the original rows I had are being reflected.. Odd

Comment: Are you sure they are added to the orders table in the same db?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change third line to:

result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

(space before "or")

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this had no effect.